# ServiceProvider not releasing memory for transient EF context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-leaks, dependency-injection

I have a windows service on .NET 4.6.2 where I register a EF6 DbContext as Transient using the .NET ServiceProvider (`System.IServiceProvider` interface). The service starts using around 30mb of memory, and after a day reaches 1Gb.

Running a profiler on the process tells me hundreds of thousands of DbContext objects waiting to be released, even though I'm disposing the context after each use.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
// registration
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient(sp => new ServiceDbContext(connectionString));
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// use
using (var ctx = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ServiceDbContext>()) { ... }
```

Adding AsNoTracking to queries reduced the memory usage, but contexts are still held in memory forever. It appears there isn't any release method for ServiceProvider.

Here is a sample object tree by running the service for a few minutes, then letting it idle for a few more minutes. 4838 is the number of times I instantiated the context. Note I forced GC after a few minutes idle before taking this snaptshot:

[image]

Is there anything else I should do to release the context other than disposing it? Or is this some limitation of the built in service provider?

Comment: What service provider exactly you use? As usual, some code example would help, showing how you register, resolve and use those contexts.

Comment: @Evk, I added more info.

Comment: It's still not clear for me what is that ServiceCollection. I only know one from System.Web.Services and I remember .net core has such class, but you are not using .net core as I understand.

Comment: It looks like you are not dispose service providers.

Comment: @Evk - I'm using net core libraries on top of .net full framework. The code is the standard way to initialize the service provider. What is not clear is why the service provider stores references for transient objects.

Comment: @gabba Disposing the service provider makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this looks like a bug in the current implementation of the ServiceProvider that for some reason tracks disposables in the root context.

https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/456

Comment: To sum up content of the issue: NEVER EVER adds to the container a service that is disposable (like a ef dbContex) in a transient mode:
i.e.
`services.AddTransient<IMyService>(...)` where `IMyService is IDisposable`
or if you really need it use a servicefactory.